# The loopback request returned an unexpected http status code, 503,

Tags: wordpress, web, hosting

I am using WordPress 5.6 version and web server is ubuntu 18.04 .
Php version 7.4
Apache 2.4
mysql
recently I am facing issue in WordPress.
"site health dashboard" showing me this error ,

"Loopback requests are used to run scheduled events, and are also used by the built-in editors for themes and plugins to verify code stability.

The loopback request returned an unexpected http status code, 503, it was not possible to determine if this will prevent features from working as expected."

pls help me to solve this issue.

Comment: There is no way to answer this from the information given.  "503" is "service unavailable."   You'd need to look in your server logs to see the cause of that.  If you are using a CDN or load balancer you'd need to consult those logs as well.